# Active class for active URLs menu (not using LI's)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this HTML code and I want to add a class of "active" to the div contained within the link that is active. (I've intentionally created this navigation WITHOUT using an unordered list.)

```
<nav role="navigation" id="navigation">
<a href="rings-c-24.html" title="Rings"><div class="primary-navigation">Rings</div></a>
<a href="earrings-c-23.html" title="Earrings"><div class="primary-navigation">Earrings</div></a>
<a href="necklaces-c-26.html" title="Necklaces"><div class="primary-navigation">Necklaces</div></a>
<a href="bracelets-and-bangles-c-22.html" title="Bracelets & Bangles"><div class="primary-navigation">Bracelets & Bangles</div></a>
</nav><!-- end of navigation-->
```

I've tried something like this, but I am certain I'm not referencing my parents and children correctly. Please help, thank you!

```
$(function(){
    var current = location.pathname;
    $('.primary-navigation').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this).parent();
        // if the current path is like this link, make it active
        if($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1){
            $this.addClass('active');
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 $(function() {
    var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
    .lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    $("#navigation a").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
    $(this).find(".primary-navigation").addClass("active");
    })
    });
```

Comment: This sort of works. I need the "active" to be added to the div within the link.

Comment: Works absolutely perfectly. Thank you SO much! Still learning my way around selectors =)

Comment: I don't have rights to do up vote yet, but will soon. Then I'll take care of that :)

Comment: How can I remove any variables after the .html in the href?

Say my href is categories.html?cPath=&cID=22 but I only want to read "categories.html"

Answer (score 1):

You can use an attribute selector for this:

```
$("#navigation a[href='"+location.pathname+"']").find(".primary-navigation").addClass("active");
```

Or if you wanted to add the class to the `<a>` tag:

```
$("#navigation a[href='"+location.pathname+"']").addClass("active");
```

Comment: Be careful with [`pathname`](http://www.w3.org/TR/Window/#location-attributes) - this attribute represents the path component of the Location's URI which consists of everything after the host and port up to and excluding the first question mark (?) or hash mark. The pathname might not exactly the `href` value in all cases